# Django :: Create new object in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I want to be able to create a new Django object called 'Comment' in javascript.

*(I understand that you can't simply declare a new object as you would do in a view method)*

I need to allow the user to be able to reply to an existing comment.

I have done the bit where if user presses 'reply' button a comment, a form appears below and saves the id of the comment which the user wants to reply to in a js variable.

However, I am struggling to find a way to finally submit all this so that I can post a new sub-comment.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do that with ajax. If you are using jQuery you could work on something like that:

Lets say you have an template called home.html, which is where you are managing the comments and everything.

home.html

```
<ul class="comments">
    <li data-id="1">This is a comment...</li>
</ul>

<textarea id="new_comment"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="send">Post comment!</button>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^comment/$', 'core.views.comment', name='comment'),
```

views.py

```
def comment(request):
    c = Comment()
    c.text = request.GET.get('text')
    c.save()
    return render(request, 'core/partial_comment.html', { 'comment': c })
```

core/partial_comment.html

```
<li data-id="{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.text }}</li>
```

Now you will need a jQuery snippet to send an async request to the server so you can create a new comment:

```
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/comment/',
           data: { 'text': $("#new_comment").val() },
           type: 'get',
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
              $(".comments").append(data);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

So let's understand what just happened here:

The user come and writes his comment on the textarea with id new_comment

The button with id "send" is listening to the click event

When the user clicks on this button it will send an ajax request to the server with this data which we called "text". Then you are on the server and you can create your Comment object. After saving it, you will return the response to the client. The "data" variable inside the ajax call will catch the result, which is "<li data-id="2">what ever he commented...</li>". Then you append it to the element where is storing your comments on the html view

Comment: This is so much better than all the tutorials I got from the google search! I will have a go at this :)

Comment: Just wondering, in the ajax request, can I pass on more than 1 variable? it seems to be using a dictionary format....

Comment: yes, you can pass as many as you want. you can even serialize a entire form